# Getting a CastClassException error in the onListItemClick method of a ListFragment

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I have a class that extends ListFragment and I'm using the Support Library. In the class's onListItemClick method, I have this line:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String item = (String) ((Fragment) getListAdapter().getItem(position)).getString(1);
    DetailFrag frag = (DetailFrag) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_stitchdetail);
    if (frag != null && frag.isInLayout()) {
        frag.setText(item);
    }
}
```

where position is a parameter that is passed to the onListItemClick method. Its value at runtime is 0 for the example app I'm building, as there's only one item in the list. This line throws the following error:

java.lang.CastClassException: android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner cannot be cast to java.lang.String

I've Googled this and searched on stackoverflow, but I don't see anything that will give me a hint as to why I can't cast this to a String. Anyone know? Thanks!

My ContentProvider code for the query:

```
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    queryBuilder.setTables(STITCHTABLE_BASEPATH);
    int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
    switch (uriType)
    {
    case STITCHES_ID:
        queryBuilder.appendWhere(SQLData.KEY_ROWID + "=" + uri.getLastPathSegment());
        break;
    case STITCHES:
        //no filter
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI");
    }
    Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(mDB.getReadableDatabase(), projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return cursor;
}
```

The code in my ListFragment for the CursorLoader:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    Intent myData = getActivity().getIntent();
    Bundle info = myData.getExtras();

    String[] dataColumns = { "stitchname" };
    int[] viewIDs = { R.id.stitchlist1 };
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.stitchlist, null, dataColumns, viewIDs, 0);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, info, (LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>) this); 

}
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String selection = "stitchlevel=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {args.getString("Level")};
    return (Loader<Cursor>) new CursorLoader(getActivity(), STITCHES_URI,
            PROJECTION, selection, selectionArgs, null);    
}
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor((android.database.Cursor) cursor);      
}
```

Comment: What do you want to get exatly? Yes this is impossible to cast ContentResolver to String.

Comment: Why not: `int item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);` then `frag.setText("" + item);`

Comment: I've added the code for the entire onListItemClick method in my question above. What this is meant to do is get the text of the item in my list and display it in a second fragment. It doesn't do much, this is just an example app I'm playing with. But I don't know why this cast isn't working. I'm using [link]http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/get-started-with-android-fragments/1050[/link] as an example.

Comment: @Asok, if I try your suggestion (without the (String) cast - that's what you meant, right?), I get "getItem(int) is undefined for ListFrag" (my ListFragment class). So I think I can't do this for ListFragments

Comment: Post the code for the adapter.

Comment: @Melanie Yes, sorry I meant to remove the `String` cast.

Comment: Sorry @dymmeh, I'm an Android newbie. What do you mean by "the adapter"?

Comment: What kind of adapter are you using>  Have you extended it?

Comment: My class extends a ListFragment. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I've posted the relevant (I hope) ContentProvider and CursorLoader code above.